# Nearest possible expressed number

Tags: code-golf

A screen consists of some LED segments like such:

[image]

The screen can be split into several(maybe one) component. Each component is a segment like above, with varying lengths. These components can be used to display any amount, including 0, of digits, as long as the component is large enough.

Every digit except 1 needs two columns of the grid to be displayed. These columns are not allowed to overlap (even a number like 67 still needs 4 columns and does not fit into a n=2 component). The digit 1 is slim, so it only needs one column.

Therefore, a number fits into a component, iff `2 * Length - (Amount of 1's) <= n+1`.

For example, the number 14617 can be displayed in a screen with the component lengths `[0, 1, 1, 2, 0]`:

[image]

Given the n's of each component and a positive integer, find the nearest positive integer that can be expressed in the screen. If multiple number are nearest, you can output either.

Shortest code wins.

## Examples

```
[1],3 => 3
[1],16 => 11
[0,0],3 => 1
[0,0],6 => 1 or 11
[2],14 => 14
[2],24 => 21
[3],999999999 => 1111
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],23 => 23
[0,3],100 => 100
```

Comment: Can digits on the same component overlap? e.g., would `88` be possible for `n=2`? What about `69` for `n=2`?

Comment: @Shaggy No, otherwise one can't even tell 13 from 8

Comment: You use `[3]` as one of your examples but don't define it anywhere. What is it *EEEI*? Very unclear whatever it is. Also details on exactly what numbers *EI* can represent would be clearer.

Comment: @Noodle9 `The exact definition of "fit the area" can be defined as:

    2*Length-(Amount of 1's) <= n+1
`

Comment: Suggested test case: `[2],110 => 111`

Comment: @Arnauld Should be covered on [1],16?

Comment: You just repeated what's already in your post which isn't clear at all.

Comment: I find Noodle9's question quite clear. What does `EEEI` mean? I can actually understand what you mean here, but "a 2-by-n grid where the 5n+2 edges are each LED segments" might be more clear (it also may not be, but other people are free to offer wording suggestions; this is what the Sandbox would clear up though).

Comment: Also, you need to more formally define what each number needs to look at and how `1` interacts with other numbers, since it only occupies one column - can a single n=2 grid represent both `18` and `81`? It's not immediately clear.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino In this question what each number look doesn't matter

Comment: I approved the edit suggestion just cuz it more fits grammar though it doesn't add anything to clarity at least to me

Comment: Does 67 fit into an `n=3`, or do those not exist?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms 67 fits n=3

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>163</s> 143 bytes

```ruby
->r,i{g=->s,r{*t,c=s;d,*q=r;n=c==1?1:2;!c||d&&(n<d+2?g[t,[d-n,*q]]:g[s,q])}
h=->n,r{g[n.digits,r]&&p(n)}
a=0;until h[i+a,r]||h[i-a,r];a+=1;end}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDNjoIwEL7zFLNsQlSKodVssrLFB6k9IEVoYgrSctgAz84OoGY7l5nvZ@ZL2@76O934FKUt0X3Jo9SStt85knObKLJ78DYxPOecnumJJR/5MKgg2JgfFbJzKRwRKjIok/JUCksecjt6FW4xuKUUZq90qR2ulEHQbAySGY@Tzjh9h0roMENmGLCL5i7JQk6TwqhxcoV1eWYLCxx6D0AIKslBAk/hQF4z/VoASlckJvFL8x9ZRT6FukWpvzIM3cdVenwjbEXY032Q5Ht@zyOvM5TE78IQbL3IMNbovWPviyyvQNUwaNN0jkDduQHtDSzz3LXaOPDnaDjdxG4h5Mx0zoK/sVXd3RVcC/js0T1uL@ZifA@/Z/oD)

*-20 bytes thanks to @Kirill L.*

My first golf in Ruby. I'm sure that it can be even shorter, but I didn't find anything.

#### Explanation

`g` (takes an array of chars, representing the number, and the displays) checks if a given number fits into the given display. `f` then checks all numbers, starting with the given integer, then i+1, i-1, i+2, ..., and outputs the first number that fits.

Comment: A few tips: the outer non-recursive function can be anonymous (so, you can omit `f=` from byte count). Then, Ruby has built-in `digits` method for integers. And `loop break` approach is almost always suboptimal, especially with several break conditions.

Comment: I also made a quick translation of my R answer to Ruby for [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU7BjoMgFLz7FS/upW7BgDZNtpb2QywHWmxL0mIjkOyu@O0uajULB97Mm2Gmceef/sp6fHgi3d4YPuhWMp1KdVPWFIbJ1KjfCtPimT7Fq/XKG8yo01Y9wOyJ9yvFFF7J0nDG6JHusiTZY9oVYXnUO9IVgpFCrGcP2TesvJUaC47Csxach4@/i6brbWXsRZjKAIM2AihLylHOgR0gRzOm25GgdGIIIrPmPzOJYgp1E6TxtMmCezNJNwuTTUz2duccfQ3nHTLHUESWG0pkU2IWanXRUjutxOUOsgav9MtZBLWzPthfMOJhapS2EA/VRv5afo4rPiBnDcQrc6/dQ8K5go82@LvkpE86jiot@z8), perhaps it can still be minified further.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
n1‘S>
⁵*ḶD“”ṭçÐḟ
‘Ç€ŒpF€ḌạÐṂḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/P8FHDjGA7rkeNW7Ue7tjm8qhhzqOGuQ93rj28/PCEhzvmcwGlD7c/alpzdFKBG5B6uKPn4a6FQKmdTQ93LPr//3@0Uex/Q0MDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 bytes

```
‘Ø½ṗⱮẎS=¥ƇƲ€ŒpF€ị⁵Ḷṭ1¤Œp€ŒP€€ḌFạÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4zDMw7tfbhz@qON6x7u6gu2PbT0WPuxTY@a1hydVOAGpB7u7n7UuPXhjm0Pd641PLQEKAqWCwCSINkdPW4Pdy08PO/hjkX///830jH@bwQEAA)

-2 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing

This is absolutely horrible. I won't be surprised if someone can halve my bytecount. I spent a decent bit of time on it; not too much - I'll keep golfing this but I think it's at least close to worth posting.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4zDMw7tfbhz@qON6x7u6gu2PbT0WPuxTY@a1hydVOAGpB7u7n7UuPXhjm0Pd641PLQEKAqWCwCSINkdPW4Pdy08PO/hjkX///830jH@bwQEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>190</strike> <strike>181</strike> <strike>215</strike> 175 bytes

```python
def f(n,i,m=["0"]):
 for g in n:m=[u+x[1:]for u in m for x in[str(d)for d in range(0,12*i)if sum(-~(b!="1")for b in str(d))<g+3]]
 return min(map(int,m),key=lambda v:abs(v-i))
```

Generates a roughly bounded list of possible ints for each segment, zero pads, tests each to see if they fit, permutates all the sequences for each segment, then finds closest int match to the input.

Thanks mypetlion and l4m2 for improving my swing!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNbsMgEIX3PsWUFTREAhNVqlWfoIsewGKB5Z@iFGIBjpJNr@6CSSW7ZTV8897T00z38HmxYlm6foABW6qpqRvEkCRVAcPFwQjagq0inQ@3hlcywTlBs@5vcWx8cLgj6duljVN27DGjvHzWRA/gZ4OP37h9qhFHq6xNsuwib@NBSFmA68PsYqy22KgJaxuoIfTc3@svZdpOwbVSrcfXoyZkUd73LsTKDZdUEKhrEMUO8peVcr7BjLJf9T/8kENs9wdtpWUMPmV82uMy43KrFpK@pvfI2SVxGg8UbblOKXZ9opEzlm2MFZOL18Do4x2R5Qc)

Comment: Change `(2,1)[b=="1"]` to `-~(b!="1")` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: You can also remove that space after `for x in`, and you don't have to use `list(m)` because `m` is already a list.

Comment: `<=g+1` => `<g+2`?

Comment: `2*10**g` => `2*i`, though some cases takes too much time then

Comment: [Failed](https://tio.run/##JU47bsMwDN19ClYTaSuA1GxGdIIOPYDgQYZlV2ipGJISJEuu7sjuxMf3Id/6LD/XeN62yc8wY5SB@gbYWCGGBuZrggVChNhzZyx3j4PineIDPiq0uSScaF@nXUkuLh6V/Gy1atuFwgz5xnh64fhhhBaHc9yd/0G6mKXTQ/2XfLmlejpEZLdiiEWy1f1A8tc/zZ/jcXJw792Y8X4KRJvL2adSi1slz4PUShEYA3U2a6pxFN9fgrY3)

Comment: Changing the search bounds to `2*i` just doesn't scale - I think I'll have to leave that out.

Comment: @l4m2 fixed for the new case with some zero padding

Comment: [180](https://tio.run/##ZZBNbsMgEIX3PsWUFTRE4ieqVKs@QRY5gMUCyz9FKcTCTpRsenV3sFPJblnBN@@9eaJ/jJ@XoKepblpoaeCO5Rn4oiSCmAzaS4QOXICQI/O7eylzk6BP0M/zO17LYYy0ZulZp0m0oWuo4FK9OuZaGK6e7r9p9VIQSWZZlWSLi310O21wW2zGa8RYF6i3PXVh5D4tZPzcPIov66vawi231UBve8fYZIehiSP2LqXhmkFRgM42UL7NVMoVFlz8qv/hpxyw4R@0lioMPiz4sMVqwWqt1oa/p/PM2SRJjp@EtqWO2rTnaJRCLDYhsj7ij1ByOhI2/QA). Treat every number start with 1(starting with something else doesn't help)

Comment: ok `m[1:]` => `m`, 0 is never nearer than 1

Comment: @l4m2 very nice! - also -1 for initialising m in func args

Comment: [164](https://tio.run/##ZZBNasMwEIX3PsVUK6lRQD@hUFOdoIsewGgh45@KVIqR5UA2vborRSnY7ayGb957PGa6xc@Ll@va9QMM2FNLnWoQQ5rUFQyXACNYD75OdDnMMeCONLzW@dLlSzB@7DGjXDxbYgeYF4eP37h9UogjkmVtlhUneRsP8p66ZOh0BaGPS0ir9diZCVsfqSP03N/Ul3FtZ@Bam3bG16MlZDXz3IeYejZcU0lAKZDVDvKXO@V8gxllv@p/@CGHVOkP2kpFCj4VfNpjUbDYqqWmr3keObskTtOrkq3UEXLXJxk5Y8XGWDWF9A2MPt4RWX8A)

Comment: [157](https://tio.run/##ZZBLbsMgFEXnXgViBMlLxCeqVKteQQZdgMWAFOygxtjCOFJW70KcSnbLCB3de3T1hke89l7Os7ENaogHB11VY4YVLQvU9AG1yHnky0Snval5qTI0GXZ6IGMMELRvLeFi5yh1DRG7m/XE0IM5fvWTjwRzTOlHu5e5OT2bqkDBximkr/Mki5yP0FH4to/qpruL0ehe6stI7odknfU42hDTwJorkBRVFZLFBvK3J@V8hRmw3/Q//IqjNOkPWkdFEp8WfNpisWCxTksF7/m9PBsTBwZppljmCLnZk4qcsaXGWDEEl8/2ecZ0/gE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 337 bytes

```lisp
(defun C(a b &aux r)(dolist(x a)(dolist(y b)(push(concatenate'string x y)r)))r)(defun P(n &aux r)(case n(0'("""1"))(1'("0""1""2""3""4""5""6""7""8""9""11"""))(t(dotimes(i n r)(setf r`(,@r,@(C(P i)(P(- n i 1)))))))))(defun F (i x)(- x(reduce'min(mapcar(lambda(p)(-(or(parse-integer p :junk-allowed t)0)x))(reduce'C(mapcar'P i))):key'abs)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNRb5swEH5ef8Xppo5z1EhAsmzNXjqhRpo0TZGiPU2T5oDTsoJhtlnJC389OydAsnXGlr7Td/fdx2HSIrf14UCZ2jUaEpKwhTeyacEIyiomHbUgR7yHraC6sY@UVjqVTmk@gXUm1w/Qwl4YIYQvPcqtSY9iqbQKNIUBIWKEQlDEMPQYY8QZ4hzxLeIC8R3ie8RbppjzmY7bu7xUlnLQXswqtwPzg27uzM0dJbSGXNCapszmEIlh9TZWwHWtYLolo7ImVUGZayplnUpDhSy3maSaeaoM1dJYNc21Uw/KQA3Ln41@msqiqJ5VBk6EomXhXibpRQJvQIjlk9oHcmsZHifKWrJUjnUmTlk39TOwkyuAgIgiATOYCY4AjlG0gCga4hBCz/8dL85xzPlz3hdxPId45GcCbofFsmfhCMLx4abxjPe5CZdFYegPv8PVVT/A0TzQCH0NFcpNuC6tyrrSSjsLtMuNdecKVnkFpJtyy1Pg78bXJvuXVW2tUsfTJfeYmxe01PbZF6/gos9J0Zs8Wt9VppTcFjAZc5bQ2e76yzHxhO/7RqdoVTW6h93y2@rjp8/dh83XJLnfbLrvXXyN3JzXi6Yw@h2cqV/FgAduMPZfyk@25l/GMf9bmT28Ds4jvrwqQsDhDw)

Gets all possible numbers that can be represented by the given component list `i`, finds the smallest distance from the numbers to input `x` and returns `x - distance`.

`F` is the main function, `C` concatenates combinations, and `P` recursively gets the possible digits for a component of size `n`.

Testing included in TIO. This can <del>probably</del> maybe be reduced by 50-75 or so bytes as is, mainly the double `dotimes` in `C`, the disgusting string hell in `P`, and the `:junk-allowed t` in `parse-integer` used by `F`. The `junk-allowed t` was needed for the case where the string is empty. I at some point tried to replace all instances of `dolist`, `reduce`, `defun`, and `mapcar` with `l`, `d`, `e`, `m` respectively but the resulting code ended up being larger at 404 bytes but someone might be able to make use of it so I'm still putting it here:

```lisp
(let((f(copy-tree'(progn(d C(a b &aux r)(l(x a)(l(y b)(push(concatenate'string x y)r)))r)(d P(n &aux r)(case n(0'("""1"))(1'("0""1""2""3""4""5""6""7""8""9""11"""))(t(dotimes(i n r)(setf r`(,@r,@(C(P i)(P(- n i 1)))))))))(d F (i x)(- x(e'min(m(lambda(p)(-(or(parse-integer p :junk-allowed t)0)x))(e'C(m'P i))):key'abs)))))))(mapc(lambda(x y)(nsubst x y f))'(dolist defun reduce mapcar)'(l d e m))(eval f))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNRb5swEH5efsXJU8c5aiQgWbZmL52iRppUTZGiPU2TZuBIWcEw27TkJX89OyeFZOsMVu747u77@HDSsrDN4YAlOcQc07rZTZwhCrAx9VZjBktUkMA71XZgJJbYgfI/O0gkNq194B6dKkead2CdKfQWOthJIyVvHrBGPbSnyhJoDAMUQkRCSow4DH0sYiGmQsyEeC/EXIgPQnwU4oYhxnylw6x2RUUWC9B@mCWXg/mJ17fm@haXuIZC4honjBYQyX6xhBVwTycZ6pCCqtBYYamqJFPY8FOsDTbKWJoU2tGWDDSw@NXqx4kqy/qZMnAylB2PomCJVeCJpFw80i5Qie1pKtWk/VRvAGrbJtZ5MyCXMmD5bLaDjPKW9VPWpgS@SRkGS8iAU8/xpErfcECuZFmqIseSxo6sm3gD7XgEECBiJGEKU8kZwDGL5hBFfR5C6PG/8/k5j7l@xvdFHs8gHvCphJt@8djz4AjC4WLSeMr3mYTbojD0m00ZjfD0uoN4wCH0Pf7gjbkvraum1qSdBcwLwzady@ToDaBuq4Rd4I/O5y37F6WuodTxh0L3UJhXsNL22Tev4ILnNNGLPErPa1MppgWxHGoWsLf7q6/HwlN890J0ylZ1q1/C/eL76vOX@/2nzbfl8m6z2f/Yx1eCyXm9IoVBb6@Mfpd93GO9sP9C3tmG/2uO8ScyO3gbnC2@PCpSwuEP)

The code is essentially wrapped in

```lisp
(let ((f (copy-tree '(progn CODE))))
  (mapc (lambda (x y) (nsubst x y f))
        '(THINGS TO BE REPLACED)
        '(THINGS TO REPLACE THEM WITH))
  (eval f))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>148</s> 147 bytes

```r
function(n,m,g=function(n,s=nchar(n),d=2-!n%/%10^(0:s)%%10-1){for(i in m)while(s&&(i=i-d[s])>-2)s=s-1;n*!s}){while(!(r=max(g(n-F),g(n+F))))F=F+1;r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxha4NADIa/71foByWZOXY5i9KV20f/xNig2NoezAh3HS0Uf7vTcxtNAs@bvEn81Nmp@5b24gYBoZ5O9qENVtrz3oMgHaxRqWQvGetP0K8Bs1kpxns3eHCJk6TH69l9HSHkOTjr1OE9fOCbMhhsULyT5zSMeF93UvC239/gBKIapBlFg3M0til458epA95UXFMLmhKOZSjRiE@zUxEvLKO7zqoHzRsyC80f618uB0z6Pzmub5egMl5qHf@UiNMP)